# restore PATH under Mac OS X

Tags: macos, variables, path, environment

Hi guys I tried to add new directory to the PATH, but instead appending I overwrote it. Is there any way to restore those default paths?

Comment: Please note that when asking questions like this, it's useful to describe what you *actually did*, so we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 2):

If you changed your PATH in a Terminal shell, simply close that Terminal window and open a new one. Changes to environment variables are local to the shell in which you change them (and any subshells created by that one).

Comment: this certainly worked, but leaves the question, how do I permanently write to PATH?

Answer (score 1):

Just restart your terminal that will assign variables based on your .profile or .bashrc ( if you are running bash )